# Node xlsx package argument for custom json parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx

I need to do json schema parsing using npm xlsx package but don’t know what should the arguments look like, could someone help? I have references for read-excel-file package but since it doesn’t handle large files I’m switching to xlsx.

```
const customMap1 = {
‘student_id’:’student_id’,
‘student_name’:’student_name’
….
}

const customeMap2 = {
‘student_id’:’student_id’,
‘course_name:’cname’,
…
}

const result = readXlsxFile(file, { map: customMap1 });
const result2 = readXlsxFile(file, { map: customMap2, sheet: ‘CourseList’});
```

Note- My excel file has 2 sheets and names are Student_db, ‘CourseList’.